# Replace text in UITextView run slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have an UITextView and I replace a word at the end of UITextView.text like below code:

```
-(void)replaceTextViewWithWord:(NSString *)word {
    NSString *currentTextViewText = self.textView.text;

    currentTextViewText = [currentTextViewText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([self.textView.text length] - [word length], [word length]) withString:word];

    self.textView.text = currentTextViewText;    
}
```

Replacement work OK, but it run so slowly and very slowly when textView become longer.

### Is there any other better way?

I try with **replaceRange:withText** for a week but  still stuck. 
Don't know how to use it to replace in my case.

Please guide! Thanks in advance! It's a urgent task.

Comment: very slowly means it takes how many seconds?

Comment: Thanks! More than 1s, but that's slowly in my case.I want the fastest way so I can input more faster.

Comment: How much text are we talking here?

Comment: I checked your code, but it is running fine instead of slow... can you place code how and where your calling this method?

Comment: Variable text! Like word document, can be many pages

Comment: when you are calling this method?

Comment: After finish enter a word @Will

Comment: What is the word you are trying to replace in this function? Are you removing certain characters or particular words from textview?

Comment: Replace what word with what in your TextView control?

Comment: have a try with MutableSTring,

Comment: Thanks @AnoopVaidya! A little bit faster.

Comment: @aăâ: You want more ?

Comment: Yes, @AnoopVaidya I think I copy to string, replace and copy back make it run slowly. Maybe I'll use dispatch.

Comment: so i am posting the same answer and hoping some one will comment on that so that we will learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Immutable string and you are creating a very very long string and assigning it to already created NSString.

Instead of `NSString` use `NSMutableString` some over head will be reduced.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FooBarCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[EditCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
        cell.mutableString = [NSMutableString string];
        cell.textView.text = cell.mutableString;
    }
    [cell.mutableString setString:@"text to show"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: he talks of replacing text in a UITextView. I don't see how this would help in that case. The TextView uses its own storage anyways

Comment: So if he doesn't use a text kit or his own class to do text rendering ;) this doesn't help here

Answer (score 0):

no there is no better way if you use UITextView (none that works for ios6 and below)

on ios7 there is textkit